# Aspnet MVC Kendo Grid Single Select by CTRL and Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a AspNet MVC Kendo Grid with selectable rows.

I want to perform the select of the row only by the combination CTRL+ click (no with only the click).

There is a way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid itself does not do this, but you can work around it to get the desired results (link to codepen demo at end). Set

selectable: false

on the grid so it does not react to row clicks. Then create your own click handler for rows checking if the CTRL key is active:

```
$("#grid").on('click', '.k-grid-content tbody tr', function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey){
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        //remove previous selections ClearSelection() 
        //does not work because selectable is false
        $("#grid .k-grid-content tbody tr").removeClass("k-state-selected");
        //select clicked row
        grid.select($(this));     
    }
});
```

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/YzzoYoe)**

Comment: I like your answer +1, but this is a workaround where there is the precondiction that the base select functionality of kendo grid is disabled. I hope for a answer that work with the base functionality. PS: This example work only for grid with single selection, i have multiple selection but I think your solution is easy to extend to multiple selection.

Comment: I have tried your solution but not work in my code. I think because the grid is not selectable and so not work the grid.select()

Comment: @VincenzoSavarese, I have updated the codepen for multiselect: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/YzzoYoe  selectable is false and the grid.select() works